# How to delete a database record using c# entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using asp.net c# with entity framework and i have tried to delete a record from database. So for that i have coded the controller part as below.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteAccount(DeleteAccountViewModel deleteaccountviewmodel)
    {
        TheFoodyContext db = new TheFoodyContext();
        string UserEmail = Session["UserEmail"].ToString();
        User user_to_update = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(s => s.email == UserEmail);

        if (user_to_update != null)
        {
            if ((deleteaccountviewmodel.Password == user_to_update.password))
            {
                db.Users.Remove(user_to_update);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("~/View/Home");

            }
        }
        //return RedirectToAction("~/View/Home");
    }
```

But in here it will give me an error because it doesn't identify 'Stores'. I don't know why is that. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You want `db.Users`, not `db.Stores`

Comment: Okay thank you. Here i have changed it. But now i have a problem about session. Here i'm deleting the row using email address. And it is the primary key of my table. After deleting i want to redirect to the home page with log out from that account and i need to clear my session. How should i do it? Here i'm not redirecting to my home page.

Comment: To clear session you have to do a UserManager.Signout call and then redirect to homepage. Are you using Aspnet.Identity?

Comment: No not Aspnet.Identity. Since that i need another way for it.

Comment: Whats "Stores" you talking about?

Comment: you can clear session value by assigning it to null: ` Session["UserEmail"] = null;`

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks. And i have another problem. I want to give a 'Yes' no 'No' pop up message to the user asking "Do you want to delete your account?"

Comment: Is there any primary key foreign key reference in store and user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code seems to be correct. db.SaveChanges(); will return value you can check whether it is removed or not.  but you are mentioned 'Stores' not identified means if you are trying to delete record from Stores table use db.Stores.Remove() if not explain clearly your problem